# LVM with uneven proportional "stripe" distribution over 2 disks of different sizes

Tags: linux, raid, storage, lvm, software-raid

Is there a way to create a "striped" LV in a VG with 2 disks of different sizes in such a way it utilizes 100% of the available space?
Linear LV would work, but I want to have the load proportionally distributed over the 2 SSDs, one 500GB and the other 1TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `-i` flag to `lvcreate` that lets you specify the number of stripes, but I'm not sure how it would handle more stripes than disks.

You could always partition your larger disk into two and then use each partition as a volume in LVM (I think), effectively telling LVM that there are 2 disks on the larger physical disk. I think it would work but I've never tried it!

Given the price of disks, I would simply buy a new disk to make a matched pair.

Comment: It works. It doesn't scale amazingly, but it works. Did a quick 4GB `dd` benchmarking and the 512GB SSD had a seq write of ~ 1.1 GB/s, 1TB had 1.3 GB/s, and a 3 stripe LV using 512GB SSD and 2 LVs on 1TB SSD as PVs had 1.6 GB/s.